# Local object are used as method parameter then that objects are not thread safe. why?

Tags: java

The only exception is of course, if one of the methods called with the LocalObject as parameter, stores the LocalObject instance in a way that allows access to it from other threads. Please calrify me on this. how its work.

```
public void someMethod(){

  LocalObject localObject = new LocalObject();

  localObject.callMethod();

// localObject is not threadsafe
  method2(localObject);
}

public void method2(LocalObject localObject){
  localObject.setValue("value");
}
```

Comment: Please give more context - it's not clear what you're referring to.

Comment: why do you have the comment "localObject is not threadsafe" ? I don't agree with this comment.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be referring to [this article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-safety.html), which has almost exactly the code snippet you present. However, this article claims that the code you show **is** thread safe.

So, it seems that you have some reason to assert that this code is **not** thread safe, but haven't told us the reason for this assertion.

For the code you show the only threading vulnerability is if LocalObject itself has some threading issues itself, for example if it had static data items that were not protected correctly.

I think perhaps you are asking for this kind of example

```
 public class UnsafeClass{
    static LocalObject bestWeHaveSeen = new LocalObject();

    public void someMethod(){

        LocalObject localObject = new LocalObject();

        localObject.callMethod();

        // localObject is not threadsafe
        method2(localObject);
    }

 public void method2(LocalObject localObject){
    if ( localObject.getValue("value") > bestWeHaveSeen.getValue("value") ){
         bestWeHaveSeen = localObject;
    }

    // some code here to compute an important value
    bestWeHaveSeen.setValue(computedValue);
 }
```

This is now not thread safe. As two different threads can access **bestWeHaveSeen**

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to make it **not** threadsafe:

```
private List<LocalObject> list = new ArrayList<LocalObject>();
public List<LocalObject> getList(){return list};

public void someMethod(){

  LocalObject localObject = new LocalObject();

  localObject.callMethod();

// localObject is not threadsafe
  method2(localObject);
}

public void method2(LocalObject localObject){
  list.add(localObject);
  localObject.setValue("value");
}
```

`method2` was modified to store the localObject *in a way that allows other threads to access it* - to a public accessible list. Another thread now could get the object from the list and set the value at the very same time. So even if we work with a local object, it is not threadsafe anymore and we have to think about synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an obvious MT safety problem with this.  'localObject' doesn't appear to be leaking anywhere enabling other threads to see it.

Comment: Issue like if a method called with parameter as local object then local object is thread safe or not.

Comment: calling a method does not in itself introduce threading problems, call is on the stack. However the method itself could be written to introduce threading problems, for example by placing a reference to the local object somewhere global.

Comment: That would be the case if someMethod() had a parameter which is mutable; but in this case it doesn't.  If 2 threads called your someMethod() each thread gets its own copy of 'localObject'

Comment: Yes we can't tell what LocalObject.callMethod() and setValue() actually do.  But like @djina said it could deal with shared data in a non MT-safe way.  So we can't guarantee thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

A scenario is not thread safe (Tn = thread n):

T1 calls `someMethod` first; T2 calls `someMethod` after that.

When executing `method2` on T1, the reference to `localObject` is changed by T2 leading to some undefined behavior.

Comment: The two calls two someMethod() would have different references to different localObjects, the references being on the call stack. They cannot interfere with each other in the code shown.

Comment: Ups, I thought that localObject was declared as class member.